# LINQ to Entities - filter on property of navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a class, `PO`, which has a 1-0..1 relationship with a navigation property in it (`Shipment`). I'd like to use LINQ to Entities to return a list of all `PO`s that a) actually have a shipment (it isn't `null`), and b) have a specific date property (`DateShipped`) within the `Shipment` within the last 14 days. How can I accomplish this?

To clarify: `PO` class --> `Shipment` class (nav property) --> `DateShipped` property. I want to filter on `DateShipped`, but my query is actually on the parent `PO` class.

Simplified:

```
public class PO {
    // misc
    public virtual Shipment Shipment { get; set; }
}

public class Shipment {
    // misc
    public virtual DateTime DateShipped { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from p in context.PO
where p.Shipment != null && p.Shipment.DateShipped >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14)
select p
```

You might also need to consider only the `date` part, either way that's some details you'll have to figure out.

Comment: I didn't know if checking for both `null` and the date difference <= 14 days in the same line was okay to do. Thank you, sorry for my stupid question!

Comment: @Vaindil - It's not only OK, it's necessary - if you don't check for null first, then if it is null the second statement will throw a null reference exception.  If there's a possibility that an object can be null, then **always** check for that before trying to access it.

Comment: @Tim, I agree, unless the query is executed directly against the database, in that case the `null` check is redundant.

Comment: @Tim - Sorry, I know null has to be checked regardless, I meant I didn't know if it was okay to do both of those together in LINQ to Entities. I was trying to figure out some sort of `if` logic inside the query, and that wasn't happening.